# WMI Query Output to variable

Tags: windows, variables, vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

I'm trying to run some commands based on OS and x86 vs. x64. When running the below code the variable remains blank. I can echo the output and see the query and property seem to be correct. Any idea why that string isn't being assigned tot he variable named `osbit`?

```
strOSbit = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor"

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strOSbit, "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

For Each objItem In colItems
  Set osbit = objItem.AddressWidth
Next
```

Comment: Does the script error, if so what is the specific error?

Comment: From your script the most obvious thing is both `wbemFlagReturnImmediately` and `wbemFlagForwardOnly` are not defined, VBScript does not know about the WMI type library so you have to define the Named Constants manually using `Const nameofconstant = value` so for example `Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = 32`. List of `WbemFlagEnum` constants [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393980(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: `AddressWidth` is `UInt16` type in WMI repository (a _Variant_ subtype `Integer` in VBScript ) so you should use `osbit = objItem.AddressWidth` as `SET` statement assigns an **object reference** to a variable or property, or associates a **procedure reference** with an event.

Comment: Really, `TypeName(objItem.AddressWidth)` returns `Long` subtype :)))

Comment: @JosefZ `UInt16` means 16-bit unsigned integer. Since VBScript's integer is 16-bit and **signed**, *as well as all other numerical variant subtypes in VBScript*, mapping `Long` is quite logical.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin of course. I have forgotten that VBScript `integer` is only 16 bit value.  Confused with `[int]` in Powershell which is `[int32]` :-(